# Vaultquerybycriteria ignores general criteria with statestatus if custom criteria included

Tags: corda

I have function from my RPC client that pulls the consumed history of a state. If I pass a custom criteria, it seem to ignore the general criteria with Vault StateStatus.

My general query looks like this:

```
QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED);
```

My custom criteria like this:

```
customCriteria = generalCriteria;
if (requestJSON.containsKey("linearId")) {
    String linearId = requestJSON.get("linearId").toString();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = getField("linearId", POSchemaV1.POSchemaPersistence.class);
    criteriaExpression = Builder.equal(fieldInfo, linearId);
    customCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(criteriaExpression);
    customCriteria = generalCriteria.and(customCriteria);
}
```

The vault query looks as below:

```
Vault.Page<PurchaseOrder> orderPage = proxy.vaultQueryByCriteria(customCriteria, PurchaseOrder.class);
    List<StateAndRef<PurchaseOrder>> orderStateAndRefList = orderPage.getStates();
```

The result seem to have unconsumed states if I pass linearId, if I ignore linearId then I get all consumed states correctly. pls let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more simple (out of the box) approach to query linear states:

```java
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria()
                                    .withStatus(Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED)
                                    .withUuid(Collections.singletonList(linearId));
```

Comment: do we have such simple approach if I have to add additional custom criteria? like state.quantity>0

Comment: The only approach is using a custom query criteria and an `.and()` operator to combine it with another criteria.

Comment: Has anyone worked with CustomCriteria that has a nested and and or like (x = 5) && (a = 12 or (b = 12 && (j > 12 or k = 1)). A complex scenario without retrieving the list of all the states with one criteria and then filtering as we know this would not be efficient for a large set of data. Basically, nesting of or/and criterias. The APIs have very little documentation.

Comment: I personally haven’t.

Comment: I may have got it to work; not as complex but basically someCriteria With Multiple Ands and nesting it with multiple Or. Like ( x = 1 and y =2 and ( a = 2 or b = 5) ) . Will have to do some more testing

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't have the linearId at hand; but have other custom attributes. It just returns UNCOSUMED states. If it is a linearState you may have to query twice, once to get UNCONSUMED state and then use that linearID to get the CONSUMED states.
How will it work if you have states that are consumed and you want to query for certain customCriteria and don't have the linearID? I don't want to query all the all states ( there can me lots of them ) and look for specific ones that match from all records that were retrieved. I assumed, VaultCustomQueryCriteria was supposed to do that.